# Reshape large dataframe by merging two columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, reshape

I'm working with a large dataframe in **R** w/ maybe 25k rows. My goal is to merge two columns (reshape DF) so that the value on the left becomes the header for values on the right. See example below. Is this possible in R? Any help is appreciated.

What I have now:

```
SomeVal1    O26FF
            8B53L
            FFS4C
            2L9PT
            Z3NW0
            X2SGF
SomeVal2    0D121
            Y0483
            YAAPT
            E0OVA
            AL4AW
SomeVal3    TFOA6
            3H5G3
```

This is what I want:

```
SomeVal1    SomeVal2    SomeVal3
O26FF       0D121       TFOA6
8B53L       Y0483       3H5G3
FFS4C       YAAPT
2L9PT       E0OVA
Z3NW0       AL4AW
X2SGF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way - change the blank (`""` to `NA`, then use `fill` to update the NA elements with previous non-NA, get the sequence by 'Col1' - `rowid` and reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(Col1 = na_if(Col1, "")) %>% 
    fill(Col1) %>% 
    mutate(rn = rowid(Col1)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Col1, values_from = Col2, values_fill = "") %>% 
    select(-rn)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  SomeVal1 SomeVal2 SomeVal3
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 O26FF    "0D121"  "TFOA6" 
2 8B53L    "Y0483"  "3H5G3" 
3 FFS4C    "YAAPT"  ""      
4 2L9PT    "E0OVA"  ""      
5 Z3NW0    "AL4AW"  ""      
6 X2SGF    ""       ""
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("SomeVal1", "", "", "", "", "", "SomeVal2", 
"", "", "", "", "SomeVal3", ""), Col2 = c("O26FF", "8B53L", "FFS4C", 
"2L9PT", "Z3NW0", "X2SGF", "0D121", "Y0483", "YAAPT", "E0OVA", 
"AL4AW", "TFOA6", "3H5G3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Comment: thank you! Trying this out now. Looks pretty good. Will let you know soon.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I also learned a ton! Much appreciated.